# Encrypted password Mcrypt php comparing form and database values

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, mcrypt

I'm creating users with encrypted passwords on database using mcrypt method like this:

```
                    $key = '1234567890123456';
                    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
                    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size);
                    $encryp_pass = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $password2, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
                    mysql_query("UPDATE usuarios SET pass_usuario = '".$encryp_pass."' WHERE id_usuario = '".$id_user[0]."' ");
```

...so that user just created is stored in database with his password encrypted.

Now, when that user logs into the system what i do (or what i'm trying to do) is encrypt the password he inputs on the textfield so then i compare that value with the value on the database. I encrypt the password the same way i did when creating the user like this:

```
$key = '1234567890123456';
$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size);
$encryp_pass = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $password, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);

$query_pass_existe = mysql_query("SELECT pass_usuario FROM usuarios WHERE nick_usuario = '".$nick."'");
$pass_user_fromDB = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_pass_existe);
```

Then i compare both passwords: the one extracted from database and the one encrypted from the login form:

```
if (utf8_encode($encryp_pass) == utf8_encode($pass_user_fromDB['pass_usuario'])) {

    echo 'both are equals';

 }else{
       echo 'they're totally different';
 }
```

Right now, i'm getting both as different. So i print them to see the result:

```
echo utf8_decode($pass_user_fromDB['pass_usuario']);
echo "<br>";
echo utf8_decode($encryp_pass);
echo "<br>";
```

but they are ALMOST alike, take a look:

```
=???0?1y?Y7h???[.?0????1m
=???0?1y?Y7h???\[.?0????1m
```

They are ALMOST the same but because of that \  i can't continue with the login successfully. I've checked the column and i have set it as: utf8_general_ci. I'm thinking on using AES encryption but i read on [this](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/22/replicating-mysql-aes-encryption-methods-with-php/) article that for mysql is better to use mcrypt.

Comment: It's probably related to not escaping the string before putting it in your SQL query. Also, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, and will be removed in PHP7. If you switch to MySQLi or PDO, you can enjoy the benefits of parameter binding.

Comment: You should not encrypt passwords, you should hash them, using PHP's built-in `password_hash` and `password_verify` functions.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara i just tried what u suggested with no success. Thank u though.

Comment: @ceejayoz can you provide with an example that best fit my requirements, please?

Comment: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-create-iv.php The results of this function are ***random***, you need to store the IV with the encrypted data or else you will not be able to decrypt it. That said, you should not use symmetric encryption on passwords, you should use a cryptographically strong hashing function like [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) which currently uses bcrypt. If you're working on something that is required to have reversible encryption you should use asymmetric crypto and keep the key *offline*.

Comment: @Alejo_Blue Examples are shown in the docs for `password_hash`.

Comment: @Sammitch This code is not random because ECB doesn't even use the IV.

Comment: @ceejayoz i tried with password_hash and password_verify but it turns out that the hosting in which i'm working on it using php 5.4 and those functions works on php5.5 and higher so not suitable for me. Thanks so much though.

Comment: I must say i ended using md5 when entering users with encrypted passwords. Then on my login form i encrypt the password and then compare it with the one i have on my database and it works just fine. But i'm not sure if this is the best solution.

Comment: @Alejo_Blue Use https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat for `password_hash` and `password_verify` in PHP 5.4. Don't encrypt passwords, *hash* them, and the best solution is to use the bcrypt standard that's used by `password_hash`.

Comment: @ceejayoz thank you again! I'll use it (y)